# Upload Image file with other data using Asp.net Web api 2?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, upload, asp.net-web-api2, multipartform-data

I built a web application using AngularJS and ASP.NET web API.

In the view of registered users I have, an input file to upload user image and other personal information such as Phone Number and Full Name. I want to send all this information in one object to the Web API.

**1. Web API Action Register:**

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            //we test if all data are correct
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
            }
```

**2 . RegisterBindingModel:**

```
    Public class RegisterBindingModel
{
        public string FullName {get;set;}
        public string PhoneNumber {get;set;}
        public HttpPostedFileBase file { get; set; } 

}
```

**3 . AngularJs View:**

```
<form role="form" name="addForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>

        <!--Personal Informations-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center" >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> select logo
                        <input type="file"
                               name="file"
                           ng-model="vm.registration.file" />

                    </div>
                            <input type="text"
                               name="FullName"
                           ng-model="vm.registration.FullName" />
                       <input type="text"
                               name="PhoneNumber"
                           ng-model="vm.registration.PhoneNumber" />
                    <div>
                        <button ng-click="vm.register()">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**4. Angular Controller:**

```
vm.register = function () {
        authService.saveRegistration(vm.registration).then(
            function (results) {
            vm.cancel();
        },
         function (error) {


         });
    };
```

**5.Angular authService:**

```
var _saveRegistration = function (registration) {

        return $http
                 .post(serviceBase + 'api/account/register', registration)
                 .then(function (response) {
            return response;
        });

    };
```

Even if I select a file in the Web API action Register I have `model.file` equal to null, but the other data like FullName and PhoneNumber I get the correct value!.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You need to be give some examples of your code and be more descriptive in order for people to help you.

Comment: Hi , thank you i just change the description.

Comment: hey man, do you solve this issue, I am facing the same problem, can you help me ?

Comment: hey, not yet i move to another things but i shoud resolve it i will let you know if i found a solution , the same for you if you found it thank you :)